# How to replace part of text on text in content control?

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I have a text in the table in docx. Whether it is possible to replace one usual word in this text with the text in content control?

My English bad (Sorry), therefore I will show that on picture.
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZFHP.png)

Can i do that programmaticaly with help OpenXmlSDK? Maybe you know some similar articles about that or you had experience with that?

Comment: My advice to you: Your question requires improvements otherwise no one will be able to help you. When asking questions in StackOverflow. Please provide evidence that you have spent at least some time investigating the problem. At this point the question looks too broad. StackOverflow isn't a best place where you would seek for general advice or raise discussion, it's about solving specific problems. Provide code example, make focus as small as possible, it should help you to obtain answer.

Comment: My solve: 1)delete all paragraph 2) past part before content control 3)past content control 4)past part after cc. But maybe I dont know something and i can do that without 1 2 4